# What's the best free software to learn "Touch-typing"?

Tags: productivity

I am not a fast typist, but I want to be one for academic purposes. So I am looking for a free typing tutor by which I can learn "touch typing" to type faster in minimum time with maximum efficiency and accuracy.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Keybr](https://www.keybr.com) . It really helped me a lot .

It automatically adjusts your lessons as you progress . It emphasizes on your weak points and help to improve them . There are different layouts according to your preference . You can set a daily goal time to practice everyday .You also get detailed statistics about your typing .

There are also multiplayer mode and typing tests to compete yourself with other players .It is completely free and web based , so you don't need to install anything . you need only email for a persistent account and no password needed .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The software may not be the key to your success. Please consider the following and then perform a search for "free typing tutor software."

Prepare for the self-instruction by purchasing a "cast-off" keyboard. An inexpensive, used keyboard can be found at thrift shops and similar places. Ensure you have the proper connection, typically USB, to avoid the seldom-used PS2 round connector. Your computer should be able to manage two keyboards connected simultaneously.

Note that the F and J keys have raised nubs (redundant?) which are used to provide tactile reference for your index fingers. Part of a good lesson plan will present to you the keys to use for specific letters. If that is not part of the program, consider to locate a better software package.

Additionally, it is important to obscure the keys to prevent you from looking at them to locate them. The key to effective typing is muscle memory, which can build quickly with a well-written program and user determination.

I've painted keyboards for friends to obscure them, but one "student" devised a different method. The keyboard was encased in a cardboard box, sized and hot-glued to provide sufficient hand movement, but full blocking of the keys.

But wait, there's more. Provide something for your eyes as well. In the case of the cardboard box user, a printed image of the keyboard was attached to the top of the box, with a dot on the F and J keys as a reminder. For the painted keyboard users, it was a simple matter to have the original keyboard on the desk above the painted one.

The box method has the advantage of not requiring one to purchase an additional keyboard along with the chore of painting it, while the painted keyboard means one does not have to print out an image of the keyboard.

Devote no more than one hour to your lesson plan with at least a few hours between lessons. If you feel you are getting weary, take a break for a day. You will find that a good portion of your previous lesson work will return more quickly when you are rested.

In the process of a quick search for free software, I also discovered online resources for learning to type. One such site is https://www.typingclub.com/sportal/ but this is not a recommendation. On the paid software side, Mavis Beacon Teaches Typing has been around almost as long as there have been personal computers. It's not particularly expensive and has a good lesson plan.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Tuxtyping. It's free. It's fun. It's cross-platform. It has multiple options. It helps.

There might be better options out there, but this is the best one I know about.

Website: http://www.tux4kids.com/tuxtyping.html

To install it on Ubuntu (a Linux distribution), do `sudo apt-get install tuxtype`.

Answer (score 0):

My young daughter successfully used KTouch - https://apps.kde.org/de/ktouch/ .

- comes with courses that build from learning the individual keys to complex texts
- tracks your progress
- has an on-screen keyboard (that can be disabled) to train you not to look at your physical keyboard, optionally highlighting the key you need to press
- free software (GPL)

It only runs on Linux, though.